# Create a calendar folder to a specific user under a specific domain

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a calendar to be shown in the list of calendars in a specefic user.

For example this calendar folder have the name `Sample` like presented by that capture:
[image]

That done with success under a the service account.

Could you please tell me how can I do it with a specific user ?.

Could you help me. Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to those threads https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert and https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert.

HTH